# Canadian income tax for foreign worker who moved back home during 2016

Tags: income-tax, canada, canada-revenue-agency

I'm an Australian who lived in Canada (specifically Saskatchewan) for two years, working at a university. I moved back to Australia on December 13th 2016 (when my contract ended).

For my 2015 tax return I just used the regular T1 General form, and that was fine. But for my 2016 return, should I still use the same form, or the one for non-residents (i.e. this one http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pub/tg/5013-g/README.html)? Or is there another form somewhere?

Comment: You will need to figure out your residential status first.